# forum in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum

Hi is there any open source forum in asp.net with c# 2.0?

If so can you post those links?

thank you,
nagu

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

Some of the other starter kits at this next link are open source projects that contain forums as part of the portal offering.

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Comment: Ya I downloaded it but I dont know how to configure it. There is no user installation guide or some thing

Comment: Installation instructions are here: http://wiki.yetanotherforum.net/Installation%20Instructions.ashx

Answer (score 0):

[stacked](http://code.google.com/p/stacked/) is an Open Source implementation of StackOverflow.. check out..

Comment: @Ramesh... Which DOT Net version is used for this... My VS 2005 and .NET 2.0 is not opening this..

Further there are lot of References...  Can I get Source for them too...